# Iterate over m^n combinations with nested loops

Tags: c++, c, loops, recursion, nested

I have an array `y` of dimension `n`, every dimension has `m` entries.
How do I iterate over all combinations of indices using nested `for` loops?

I'd like to get all possible combinations of sums like shown in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        ...
        for (int k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
            z = x[0] + y[i]*x[1] + y[j]*x[2] + ... + y[k]*x[n];
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not possible using `for` loops, how else can it be achieved?

Comment: you can use a std::vector of size N nested loops and update each entry at each loop.

Comment: You can use recursion instead. it can prove to be a better alternate

Comment: @Daniyal Shaikh thanks for the response . Im a little bit confused  how to use the recursion in this case

Comment: If you explain your exact problem to me i might of help. Thanks

Comment: I don't get the `x=x[0]+...` what is `x` that you assign? Is it different from the `x` array? What are you gong to do with the results?

Comment: I am sorry i have a mistake . Lets say z = x[0]+ x[1] *y[i]... The result is indepented from x and y vectors .@Daniyal Shaikh @JHBonarius

Comment: Won't `z` just be overwritten in every iteration of the loop? The final value of `z` will just be `x[0] + y[m-1][*x[1] + y[m-1]*x[2] + ...`

Comment: @Miguel yeah, what cigien says. doesn't make much sense. Please give a realistic example. Else it's difficult to think along.You now have **two** answers, and with each you comment "Maybe i dont make the question clear enough". No! it's definitely not clear enough. Please try to be clear.

Comment: In the comments below, you ask for `n` counters, but your example is using `n-1` counters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution to the problem, probably not the optimal one, but illustrates the idea. Since you need to index y with as many indices at a time as there are y's, you need an array. The array's indices will be incremented each iteration, starting at the 0th index. When the 0th index reaches m, we carry over a 1, just like normal addition. When the integer at that next index reaches m, we carry over a 1 to the next index. When all of the indices went from 0 through m - 1, we know we're done. [Test it in the browser if you wish](http://cpp.sh/8f2uk).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> y = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> x = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> indices = { 0, 0, 0 };
    int m = y.size();
    int sum = 0;
    
    int index_to_increment_next = 0;
    
    while (index_to_increment_next < m)
    {
        // sum up at current indices
        sum += x[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            sum += x[i + 1] * y[indices[i]]; 
        }
        
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (indices[j] < m - 1)
            {
                // increment indices
                indices[j]++;
                break;
            }
            // when the index reaches m, reset it to 0 
            // and try to increment the next one
            indices[j] = 0;
        }
        
        // on the last iteration, this will be equal to m
        // and all of the indices will be reset back to 0
        index_to_increment_next = j;
    }
    
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

### Update

> I need a separate sum for every possible combination z = x[0] + y[i]*x[1] + y[j]*x[2] + ... + y[k]*x[n] where i,j,...k are n counters and take on values from 0 to m.

Just save the individual sums on each iteration and store them in e.g. a vector. [See the code](http://cpp.sh/9rhvv).

```cpp
// declare above the while
std::vector<int> sums;

// ...

int sum = x[0];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    sum += x[i + 1] * y[indices[i]]; 
}
sums.push_back(sum);
```

Comment: Maybe i dont make the question clear enough but I need a seperate sum for every possible combination   z  = x[0] + y[i]*x[1] + y[j]*x[2] + ... + y[k]*x[n]    i,j,...k  are n counters and takes values from 0 to m

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then as [Daniyal Shaikh said above in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339053/n-nested-loops-to-create-nm-sums#comment119025846_67339053)

> You can use recursion instead. it can prove to be a better alternate

An easy implementation of n for-loops is:
(`n_counter` and `z` are globals)

```
int n_counter = 0; // which is the 1,2,3 of your y[i]*x[**1**]
int z = x[0];      // all possible combinations of sums at every iteration

void recursion(int n, int m){
   n_counter++;
   for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++){
      z += y[i]*x[n_counter];
   }

   if(n_counter<=n){ // go deeper n times, which is equal to n for-loops
      recursion(n, m);
   }

   return;
}
```

Every time we get deeper in the recursion, `n_counter` will increase because we need the number that increases.

For example with number 2: ".. + y[j]*x[**2**] + ..".

Lastly, all you have to do is to print z.

Comment: Maybe i dont make the question clear enough but I need a seperate sum for every possible combination z = x[0] + y[i]*x[1] + y[j]*x[2] + ... + y[k]*x[n]  i,j,...k are n counters and takes values from 0 to m

Comment: You can add under for-loop an array with size m, to save every sum separately.